# Javascript onload after redirect

Tags: javascript

in my Javascript code I am loading a page, and then would like to perform some functions. I tried to use solutions like `window.onload`, but that is after my html (blank page with just the JS) loads, I need the function to perform after the page I am reffering to is loaded.
I am using this code:

```
this.document.location.href = myurl;
```

And after this loads, I would like to call some function. Is there a way to do so?
Thanks

**EDIT:**

I can not edit the target page source code.

Comment: If you refer to an external page, you can not modify, what about loading it into an iframe at your page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the value of `document.location.href`, you are essentially doing a redirect.

You can either just do whatever you want to do within the loaded page itself or if you don't have cross domain issues, do xhr of the page you're wanting to load dynamically, query the body, replace content of your current body and also replace head contents i.e. style, title and scripts etc. You could then execute any script you want.

Extra note: This is quite a tricky thing to do, I've done this a few times before - and its proven quite problematic due to the fact that you don't actually get a fully parsed document object that you can just query so simply, you only receive a huge string. One hack that I've thought of using is actually just loading everything within an iframe allowing easy querying which is actually documented - extra reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM)

Answer (score 0):

`window.load` takes forever to fire because it waits for all images and assets to load on the page.

It sounds like the best solution for you would be to poll for the document to be finished loading. Here's a simple example:

```
(function poll(){
    if(document.readyState === "complete"
    {
        // Your code here
    }
    else
        setTimeout(poll,500);
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Place the 'window.onload = myFunction(){...}' inside the page, which will be loaded.

*this.document.location.href*
will open the page like you typed it into the browser address bar and your onload-script in the old page will not be executed in the new one.
By the way, you can shortcut it to *document.location = myUrl*
See the [Document-API at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.location)

Comment: My fault, I should have stated this before - I can not edit the target page source code, so I can't place any code there. It is not my webpage, I am loading an external one.